# Scala trait as a function return type

Tags: scala, oop, traits

If I have traits A and B

```
trait A {
  def funcA(a: Int): B
}

trait B {
  var bvariable: Int
  def funcB(b: Int): Int
}
```

Is it possible to have the above? If yes, I can override the functions in a class but how do I initialize `bvariable` since I cannot create an instance of a trait and hence no constructor?

Comment: When you declare a trait as return type, you return an object whose type implements that trait, no more, no less, uh?

Comment: What hinders you to instantiate instances of classes extending `B`? E.g. instantiation of anonymous classes `val x = new B { bvariable = 42; def funcB(i: Int) = i * ; }` works as expected, you don't need a constructor for that.

Comment: Is it just like Java interface, when there is a function with the return type of an interface, it returns an object of the class that implements the interface?

Comment: @KseniaM It's kind-of like Java-interfaces with default method implementations and variables, but the traits [compose quite differently](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html). Still not entirely clear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a trait the class that implements it must provide an implementation for the methods of the trait and values for its members. For example classB could implement trait B like this:

```
class classB extends B{
  override var bvariable: Int = 0

  override def funcB(b: Int): Int = {
    0
  }
}
```

If you dont provide a value for bvariable scala compiler will complain that not all the members of the trait have been implemented